# Trying to use Ftype in .bat file to change default web browser: "Error occurred while processing: InternetShortcut"

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation

I'm trying to set up two .bat files, one to schedule at 9am to change my default browser to my work profile of Firefox and one to run at 5pm to change my default browser back to my personal profile on Firefox. This is the first .bat I came up with:

```
assoc .url
Ftype InternetShortcut="C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe -P "Work"" %1 %*
```

I'm running this through the command prompt with administrator privileges and this is the error I'm getting:

```
Access is denied.
Error occured while processing: InternetShortcut.
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax? I checked the Microsoft Docs of ftype (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftype) and didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this confuses me more. Are you saying I shouldn't be using Ftype at all and instead be changing some kind of registry key?

Comment: `assoc .url` just displays the current association of `.url` file types – are you aware of that?

Comment: Welp I am now. Good to know for the future. Still doesn't help my Access is denied problem though.